# PANDAS - properly doing nested groupby for more than one column (a couple columns make a unique identifier)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas-groupby

Please ignore the copious amounts of columns, it was far easier to copy and paste my current example.

The problem at hand: four of the columns below, in combination, are my unique identifiers of a row. These columns are *param01, param02, param03, param04*. I want to be able to observe how all the other columns change as a function of *param04* while I pick a unique combination of *param01, param02, param03*. Namely if the combination of `param01,param02,param03` correspond to more than one entry of `param04`, I want to keep that result.

Ideally by the end of the result, I want a `table` / `datafram` reduced to one with this unique combination of *param01, param02, param03* that has more than one entry of *param04*. Eventually to plot any of the other columns as a function of changing *param04*, for a specific combination of the other params.

I'm looking for some idea of how to do this in **pandas** or `SQL` ish

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>&lt;100&gt;_poisson </th><th>avg wall time (s) </th><th>bulk_hill </th><th>c_{11} </th><th>c_{12} </th><th>c_{44} </th><th>homo_poisson </th><th>param01 </th><th>param02 </th><th>param03 </th><th>param04 </th><th>shear_hill </th><th>time_generated </th><th>young_hill</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>0 </td><td>0.264 </td><td>0 </td><td>91.6 </td><td>160.0 </td><td>57.4 </td><td>75.8 </td><td>0.214 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.8 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:39.254305 </td><td>157.3</td></tr><tr><td>1 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.5 </td><td>154.9 </td><td>56.8 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>70.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.2 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:43.696335 </td><td>155.4</td></tr><tr><td>2 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>90.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.2 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:47.814102 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>3 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:52.052636 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>4 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.5 </td><td>154.9 </td><td>56.8 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>130.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:55.752065 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>5 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>150.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:59.631407 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>6 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:03.275825 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>7 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>40.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:07.057999 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>8 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>60.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:11.655756 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>9 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.3 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>7.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>63.9 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:15.474917 </td><td>154.8</td></tr><tr><td>10 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.4 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>9.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>63.9 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:19.727918 </td><td>154.9</td></tr><tr><td>11 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.9 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>13.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.2 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:24.841238 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>12 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>2.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:29.916590 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>13 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>3.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:35.019309 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>14 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:39.904661 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>15 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>6.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:44.982282 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>16 </td><td>0.017 </td><td>0 </td><td>287.3 </td><td>799.5 </td><td>47.7 </td><td>120.4 </td><td>0.243 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>177.9 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:50.124683 </td><td>442.3</td></tr><tr><td>17 </td><td>0.264 </td><td>0 </td><td>91.6 </td><td>159.9 </td><td>57.5 </td><td>76.2 </td><td>0.213 </td><td>40.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>65.0 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:54.744038 </td><td>157.7</td></tr><tr><td>18 </td><td>0.264 </td><td>0 </td><td>91.7 </td><td>160.1 </td><td>57.5 </td><td>76.2 </td><td>0.213 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>65.0 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:58.547615 </td><td>157.8</td></tr><tr><td>19 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.4 </td><td>154.8 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.4 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>60.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:13:03.234323 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>20 </td><td>4.923 </td><td>0 </td><td>-5.8 </td><td>0.0 </td><td>0.0 </td><td>46.3 </td><td>-1.138 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>10.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>208.5 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:13:08.527995 </td><td>-57.4</td></tr><tr><td>21 </td><td>0.015 </td><td>0 </td><td>728.8 </td><td>2305.4 </td><td>96.4 </td><td>75.6 </td><td>0.334 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>20.0 </td><td>5.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>272.0 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:13:15.060308 </td><td>725.7</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: your desired output is unreadable, please fix it

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm not entirely sure what you mean, can you clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly:

> I want a table / dataframe reduced to one with this unique combination of param01, param02, param03 that has more than one entry of param04.

So you want an analog of sql `SELECT param01,param02, param03 GROUP BY param04 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

If so:

```
import pandas as pd

html=r'<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>&lt;100&gt;_poisson </th><th>avg wall time (s) </th><th>bulk_hill </th><th>c_{11} </th><th>c_{12} </th><th>c_{44} </th><th>homo_poisson </th><th>param01 </th><th>param02 </th><th>param03 </th><th>param04 </th><th>shear_hill </th><th>time_generated </th><th>young_hill</th></tr><tr><td>0 </td><td>0.264 </td><td>0 </td><td>91.6 </td><td>160.0 </td><td>57.4 </td><td>75.8 </td><td>0.214 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.8 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:39.254305 </td><td>157.3</td></tr><tr><td>1 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.5 </td><td>154.9 </td><td>56.8 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>70.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.2 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:43.696335 </td><td>155.4</td></tr><tr><td>2 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>90.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.2 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:47.814102 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>3 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:52.052636 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>4 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.5 </td><td>154.9 </td><td>56.8 </td><td>76.8 </td><td>0.211 </td><td>130.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:55.752065 </td><td>155.3</td></tr><tr><td>5 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>150.0 </td><td>50.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:11:59.631407 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>6 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>30.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:03.275825 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>7 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>40.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:07.057999 </td><td>155.2</td></tr><tr><td>8 </td><td>0.268 </td><td>0 </td><td>89.3 </td><td>154.7 </td><td>56.6 </td><td>76.7 </td><td>0.210 </td><td>110.0 </td><td>60.0 </td><td>11.0 </td><td>4.0 </td><td>64.1 </td><td>2019-02-14 11:12:11.655756 </td><td>155.2</td></tr></tbody></table>'
df = pd.read_html(html,header=0)[0]
df_params=df[['param01','param02', 'param03', 'param04']]
df_params.groupby('param04').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     param01  param02  param03  param04
 0     50.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 1     70.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 2     90.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 3    110.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 4    130.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 5    150.0     50.0     11.0      4.0
 6    110.0     30.0     11.0      4.0
 7    110.0     40.0     11.0      4.0
 8    110.0     60.0     11.0      4.0
```

## Edit: analogue of EXISTS to return all columns

Analogue of:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    source_data T 
    JOIN (SELECT param01,param02, param03 GROUP BY param04 HAVING 
          COUNT(*) > 1) FLT 
      ON T.param01 = FLT.param01 
         AND T.param02=FLT.param02 
         AND T.param03=FLT.param03
```

is:

```
pd.merge(df, df_params.groupby('param04').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1), on=['param01','param02','param03'])
```

It must be correct although I suppose it must be possible to write more concisely.

Comment: Yes almost, but I also need the rest of the columns still. How would I incorporate that given your existing answer?

Comment: I did not check thouroughly but try: `df.groupby('param04').filter(lambda x: len(x[['param01','param02', 'param03']]) > 1)`. It returns the same 8 rows. You need more test data.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure that my previous comment was correct

Comment: I'll update my table with more test data. But you are correct that one liner didn't work. Updated.

Comment: Look at edited example. It must be correct. Remove duplicated columns if you needed.

Comment: You were really close! Maybe it was me not stating exactly what I wanted; I find the following works:

pd.merge(df, df_params.groupby(['param01','param02', 'param03']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1), on=['param01','param02', 'param03','param04'], how='right')

I wanted the left join of the unique identifiers from the original database onto the newly trimmed one.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem. Please take time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions in future.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you update your post or shall I?

Comment: It makes sense if you want to practice in improving quality of your original post. In this case I suggest you: a) prepare MVCE, b) post desired output. From the content of your post as is now: it's unclear for me why `right` was needed. Chose yourself: leave it as is and move forward or improve.